# Mysterious type conversion warning when using sys/socket.h macro

Tags: c, gcc, type-conversion, solaris, gcc-warning

I'm trying to resolve conversion warnings in our C code base on Solaris 11 64-bit using GCC 9.1 (iso9899:1999) and GNU make 4.2, and I came across this one:

```
warning: unsigned conversion from ‘int’ to ‘long unsigned int’ changes value from ‘-8’ to ‘18446744073709551608’ [-Wsign-conversion]
  187 |     char ccmsg[CMSG_SPACE(sizeof(int))];
      |                      ^~~~~~~~~~
```

I know that `CMSG_SPACE` is defined in `sys/socket.h` as:

```
/* Amount of space + padding needed for a message of length l */
#define CMSG_SPACE(l)                           \
    ((unsigned int)_CMSG_HDR_ALIGN(sizeof (struct cmsghdr) + (l)))
```

However, I am not understanding where the conversion is happening and how to resolve it. Google was of no help.

**EDIT**
Here is some more info from the header file, as requested in the comments:

```
#if defined(__sparc)
/* To maintain backward compatibility, alignment needs to be 8 on sparc. */
#define _CMSG_HDR_ALIGNMENT 8
#else
/* for __amd64 (and other future architectures) */
#define _CMSG_HDR_ALIGNMENT 4
#endif  /* defined(__sparc) */

#define _CMSG_DATA_ALIGNMENT    (sizeof (int))
#define _CMSG_HDR_ALIGN(x)  (((uintptr_t)(x) + _CMSG_HDR_ALIGNMENT - 1) & \
                    ~(_CMSG_HDR_ALIGNMENT - 1))
#define _CMSG_DATA_ALIGN(x) (((uintptr_t)(x) + _CMSG_DATA_ALIGNMENT - 1) & \
                    ~(_CMSG_DATA_ALIGNMENT - 1))
#define CMSG_DATA(c)                            \
    ((unsigned char *)_CMSG_DATA_ALIGN((struct cmsghdr *)(c) + 1))
```

Comment: And how `_CMSG_HDR_ALIGN` is defined?

Comment: You can call GCC with `-E` to see how the expanded source looks like. That should give you some hint.

Comment: The `-8` is coming from `~(_CMSG_HDR_ALIGNMENT - 1)`, and the `long unsigned int` conversion is coming from `uintptr_t`. The compiler is warning about conversion of `-8` to `uintptr_t` before applying the `&` operator.

Comment: This seems like a spurious warning, at best.  The conversion of `-8` to `unsigned long int` is clearly covered by [**6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers**, paragraph 2 of the C standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3p2): "Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-8` is coming from `~(_CMSG_HDR_ALIGNMENT - 1)`, and the `long unsigned int` conversion is coming from `uintptr_t`.

The compiler is warning about conversion of `-8` to `uintptr_t` before applying the `&` operator.

> NOTE: answer is from a comment left by @jxh