# Explicit casting in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, casting

After reading several SO posts on the subject I am still confused, mainly concerning to integer and boolean variables/expressions.

**A. Integer expressions**

Suppose I want to use modulo expression in a floating point computation, what, if any, is the most correct of the following? Is there any difference between C and C++? or should I just trust the compiler to make the correct conversion?

```
double sign;
int num = rand() % 100;
//want to map odd num to -1.0 and even num to 1.0
//A
sign = -2 * (num % 2) + 1;
//B
sign = -2.0 * (num % 2) + 1;
//C
sign = -2.0 * (num % 2) + 1.0;
//D
sign = -2 * (num % 2) + 1.0;
//E
sign = -2 * (double)(num % 2) + 1;
//F
sign = -2.0 * (double)(num % 2) + 1;
//G
sign = -2.0 * (double)(num % 2) + 1.0;
//H
sign = -2 * (double)(num % 2) + 1.0;
```

**B. Boolean expressions**

Can I use a boolean expression, **safely**, as an element in floating / integer computations without explicit casting? Is there a difference between C and C++?

```
double d_res = 1.0;
int i_res = 1;
int num = rand() % 10;
d_res = d_res + (num > 5);//or d_res = d_res + (double)(num > 5)?
i_res += (num > 5);//or i_res += (int)(num > 5)?
```

Comment: *"should I just trust the compiler to make the correct conversion"* - no, because compiler mostly relies on programmer to make correct conversions.

Comment: For reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion

Comment: perhaps the most striking difference between c and c++ is that in c++ you should use `static_cast`

Comment: sorry misread the question, will remove misleading comment

Comment: @VTT Good point in general, but in this case, I'd say "Yes, because when you've confirmed that the straightforward expression `-2 * (num % 2) + 1` falls into the broad case where the implicit conversions are sufficient, you can trust the compiler to make them."

Comment: @SteveSummit Expression `-2 * (num % 2) + 1` itself does not involve any conversions. And even when implicit conversions are sufficient and yield expected results they are still evil. There are some good reasons why safer languages completely prohibit or limit implicit conversions only to situations when they won't lead to data loss or some UB.

Comment: @VTT You will never convince me, so there's no need to prolong the argument, but for the record: In my opinion, implicit conversions between most arithmetic types (between integer and floating point, or numbers of different sizes) are a Fine Thing, and I've always been glad that C performs them.  Having to insert explicit conversions between, for example, integer and floating point is (again, in my opinion) a sign that someone has still not fully accepted that assembly-language programming is too much work, that HLL's exist to take care of the nuisance work for us.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**A.** The initialization

```
double sign = -2 * (num % 2) + 1;
```

is perfectly well-defined.  That's what I'd use; I don't think there's any need to complicate things with extra casts or anything.

C and C++ are well-defined and convenient in their implicit conversions between integer and floating-point types.  Explicit conversions are usually not needed.  In my experience there are only three things to worry about:

- Code like `double ratio = 1 / 3` doesn't do what you want; you need to force one of the operands to `/` to be floating-point.  (This has nothing to do with your question, but it's an extremely easy mistake to make.)
- Overflow, if one type or the other can't represent the value.  (Also not a problem for your example.)
- Overzealous compilers.  Many compilers will "helpfully" warn you that you might lose precision when converting from `double` to `float`, or from a floating-point type to an integer.  So you may need explicit casts to silence those warnings.

**B.** Asking for the numeric value of a Boolean is perfectly well-defined (is guaranteed to give you a nice, clean, 1 or 0), so your second fragment should be fine also.  (I know this is true for C, and per a comment below, it's true for C++ also.)

Comment: There are no additional concerns for C++: http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.fpint#2 (similarly for the [integral case](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.integral#2)).

Comment: *"C and C++ are well-defined and convenient in their implicit conversions between integer and floating-point types."* - this is ridiculous given how often people shoot their legs with these conversions. Those "overzealous compilers" are actually trying to protect you from introducing greave bugs, and no, explicit cast should not be used just to "silence those warnings", it should be used when that particular kind of conversion was intended. Even if implicit conversion produces expected values it may still be an issue because it shouldn't be there on the first place.

Comment: @VTT Not going to argue about this further (see my comment to you in the question).  To me the situation here is analogous to me saying "Automobiles are safe and reliable and convenient for moving from place to place quickly" and you saying "This is ridiculous given how often people maim and kill themselves and each other with these conveniences."  Any tool needs to be used with an appropriate level of care; no tool can prevent against all misuse.  C requires more care than some other languages, to be sure, but that doesn't make its design choices intrinsically wrong.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Thanks for the citation.  Answer updated.

Comment: *Overzealous compilers. ...  So you may need explicit casts to silence those warnings.* [As if...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57950803/mysterious-type-conversion-warning-when-using-sys-socket-h-macro).  ;-)